# Заполнение двумерного динамического массива в отдельной функции C++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Не понимаю как заполнить 2D динамический массив в отдельной функции, мне нужно передать его в качестве параметра и его размерность.
Создаю его в main

```
int N = 0;
cin >> N;
int **dinamic_array = new int*[N];   
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {          
        dinamic_array[i] = new int[N];
```

То есть размерность его узнается при исполнении программы. И мне надо заполнить его рандомными числами в ОТДЕЛЬНОЙ функции. Знаю, что то делается через тип size_t, но никак не могу найти ответа нигде.

Answer (score 1):

Так в чем проблема, создаете функцию:

`void generateArray(int **arr, int n){
//Тело
}`

И вызываете ее следующим образом:

`generateArray(dinamic_array, n);`

**UPD**

И да, возможно вы путаете понятия размер и размерность. Размер - количество элементов в массиве (строки*столбцы, если матрица прямоугольная). Размерность - количество ее измерений (двумерная, трехмерная и т.д). Размерность определяется по указателям (`*array` - одномерный массив, `**array` - двухмерный массив). Это вам никак передавать не надо. Судя по всему, вам необходимо передать размер

Answer (score 1):

Функция для ввода значений двумерного массива:

```
void inputArray(int **arr, int N)
{
    cout << "Введите элементы массива A " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << "A[" << i << "][" << j << "]=";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
inputArray(dinamic_array, N);
```

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что вы не создаете двумерный массив. Вы создаете несколько одномерных массивов, первый из которых содержит элементы в виде указателей типа `int *`, а в все остальные динамически созданные массивы содержат элементы типа `int`.

Поэтому, в функцию вам следует передать указатель на первый элемент массива с элементами типа `int *`, а также количество элементов в этом массиве и количество элементов в каждом создаваемом массиве с элементами типа `int`. Например:

```
void fill( int **dynamic_array, size_t rows, size_t cols );
```

И внутри функции соответствующий цикл мог бы выглядеть как:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
    { 
         dynamic_array[i][j] = SomeValue;
    }
}
```

Если число "строк" и "столбцов" равны между собой, то достаточно передать лишь одну размерность массива. Например:

```
void fill( int **dynamic_array, size_t n );
```

И внутри функции соответствующий цикл мог бы выглядеть как:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    { 
         dynamic_array[i][j] = SomeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, это должно помочь:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

template<class T>
auto make_2d_array(size_t n) {
    auto ar = new T*[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {          
        ar[i] = new T[n];
    }
    return ar;
}

template<class T>
void fill_rand(T ** ar, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            ar[i][j] = rand();
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
void print(T ** ar, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            std:: cout << ar[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std:: cout << "\n";
    }
}

template<class T>
void clear_2d_array(T** ar, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {          
        delete[] ar[i];
    }
    delete[] ar;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(nullptr));
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    auto a = make_2d_array<int>(n);
    fill_rand(a, n);
    print(a, n);
    clear_2d_array(a, n);
    return 0;
}
```